# Killing the toughest dragon on the Darkside of Xeen

Tags: might-and-magic-world-of-xeen

I figured I'd go to my grave without knowing the answer to this, but is there any way to kill the dragon in the clouds on the Dark Side of Xeen in the top left corner of the map?

It's been a long time since I've played the game and I'm sure that's the only thing I've never done.  I've been sans-5 1/4 drive for a while, so I'm just asking this as a purely speculative question, hopefully someone knows the answer and has done this mighty feat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing you're talking about the Mega Dragon.  I'll refer you to this thread: http://www.abandonia.com/vbullet/showthread.php?p=288395 where they cover most of the strategies to use.

Answer (score 4):

I've done it, so yes, it is tough, but it can be done.

To do so, I avoided everything single item and location in the game that awarded a static level increase.

I played the game spending money on level increases until there wasn't enough gold left in the game to provide additional levels. (The cost for one level increase exceeded the greatest treasure pile in the game).

At this point, I went through the entire game again activating all the items, fountains, NPCs, etc., that would provide a free level increase. By doing this, I was able to attain a higher level than possible otherwise. (I believe my level was around 160). 
I killed the megadragon but I believe only two of my characters survived the ordeal.

Comment: Impressive, most impressive...

Answer (score 2):

Sure, why not? >L100 characters + full Obsidian kit + 2500HP boost + other Well boosts + Day of XXX spells. Melee weapons with bonus against dragons are a bonus. If you want cheese, use the Xeen Slayer Sword.

Note that the Barbarian dishes out the most damage (manual is wrong on the Knight), based on the number of attacks per level.